# how to block a user from opening new process like internet explorer or firefox?

Tags: c#, process

I am looking for a way to block a user from opening new IE or firefox windows. Is there a way to do this using c#. I am looking at system.diagnostics

Comment: You would need a daemon running with sufficient priveledges.

Comment: @lpthnc, no such thing as deamons in windows.

Comment: @shoosh, consider that he said "Windows service" instead of "daemon"?

Comment: OP, the way you word your question it sounds as if your user will have "a" IE/FF window open, but you don't want more of them.  Do you have a plan to prevent them from opening new tabs?

Comment: @JMD, that would still not make it a right or even relevant answer.

Comment: I need to do this to restrict user when he is taking an online exam. I saw similar functionality on http://www.questionmark.com and they open the browser in full window and there is no way for the user to exit their window using tab or eacape etc. also they stop users from opening new windows. I need to do something similar.

Comment: I really don't want to answer all questions like this, but the answer is that it's impossible if you restrict yourself to C# and System.Diagnostics.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a windows service since it runs on background and use this code to terminate a process (the code terminates a detected running internet explorer process)

```
while (true)
        {
            StartLoop:
            try
            {
                foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process process in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses())
                {
                    if (process.ProcessName.ToUpperInvariant().Equals("IEXPLORE"))
                        process.Kill();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                goto StartLoop;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about making a group policy for the "testing account" that excludes most of the start menu and the desktop. Make your program the only one that can run.

It won't guarantee that another process won't be started, but it will certainly make it more difficult.